# Weird GDAL error for compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, gdal

So I thought I installed GDAL correctly using aptitude, and all my makefile has is 
`   g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient   -I/usr/include/gdal -lgdal1.7.0'

But I am getting this error on my make "ubuntu vm"

```
`g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient   -I/usr/include/gdal -lgdal1.7.0
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:65:0,
             from /usr/include/gdal/gdal_priv.h:58,
             from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<_Tp,        _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_check_len(std::vector<_Tp,   _Alloc>::size_type, const char*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1244:40: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:66:0,
             from /usr/include/gdal/gdal_priv.h:58,
             from main.cpp:5:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::_M_check_len(std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::size_type, const char*) const’:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:1026:45: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

`

Don't really know how to solve this one
Here is all my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sql.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   GDALDataset  *poDataset;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your gdal_priv.h file ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like an STL/vector issue than a GDAL specific problem. Something is going wrong when gdal_priv.h does

```
#include <vector>
```

I'd first check if you can compile something like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   std::vector<int> foo;
}
```